# How to vertically center span with float:right in div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to vertically center span with float:right in div?

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5>TEST</h5>
    <span class="fa fa-info"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-text">
      TEXT<br />
      TEXT<br />
      TEXT<br />
      TEXT<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.card {
  width: 200px;  
}

.card-header h5 {
  display: inline;
}

.card-header span {
  float: right;
}
```

In this example fa icon in span is align to top.

How can I vertically align this span?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zj3cubtd/

Comment: If you know you ever gonna use only one H5 line, you can simply add line-height to the element: .card-header span { line-height: 1.6875; }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for flexbox. Add the following css and it should work as expected:

```
.card-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card-header h5 {
  margin: 0; /* It doesn't need 'display: inline'. Just get rid of its margin */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to center h5?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the h5 centered horizontally (with the span still staying to the right)?

Comment: Yes, I would like that

Comment: If you add `width: 100%;` and `text-align: center;` to `.card-header h5`, that should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will work.

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;  
}

.card-header h5 {
  display: inline;
}

.card-header span {
  float: right;
}
.card-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5>TEST</h5>
    <span class="fa fa-info"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-text">
      TEXT<br />
      TEXT<br />
      TEXT<br />
      TEXT<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```